# How to create a staff-dynamic in a Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project related to a company, and it'll have a section called "News and Events", which will have "News", "Photo Gallery", "Event Calendar" and "Newsletter" as sub-sections..

My idea is to:
-Make "News" a blog
-Make "Events Calendar" something like Google Calendar(showing month, then can 'zoom' into a day
-"Newsletter" page where you put your email and starts receiving the newsletter of the company

So far, so good, but here's the real problem:

- How to make this a staff-friendly environment? The company's
  marketing team will be the ones to post in this page, and I don't
  find anywhere something on how to do this in a django project(in
  Wordpress I found some topics, but couldn't apply in Django).. .
- So I need to create a page for the staff to edit?
- Know a good tutorial of a complete blog in Django? I followed a few that I found but it's just for the basic idea of a blog..

Anyway, I know that this is not the ideal post here, but I did some research and came out empty...

If this is again't a rule of StackOverflow, please tell that I'll delete the post.
Thanks.

Comment: This type of question is not encouraged on SO, so I would suggest you delete it, but it's a reasonable question so I'll give you a hint. You are looking for a user friendly CMS for Django. Check Django packages https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/cms/. I have had good experiences with Wagtail.

Comment: Wagtail is exactly what I need, thanks a lot, I was trying to find a package like this but with no success...